# Differences between 喜欢, 要, and 想?

Tags: difference, verbs

Could someone explain to explain me the difference between the three verbs
喜欢 (*xihuan*), 要 (*yao*), and 想 (*xiang*)?

- 我喜欢喝一杯啤酒。 (*wo xihuan he yi bei pi jiu*)
- 我要喝一杯啤酒。 (*wo yao he yi bei pi jiu*)
- 我想喝一杯啤酒。 (*wo xiang he yi bei pi jiu*)

When do I have to use it?

Comment: consult grammar on modal verbs (能愿动词）表示意愿的：要、想、愿意、肯、敢，and dictionary on verb 喜欢

Comment: the first sentence doesn't make sense. it should be "我wo3喜xi3欢huan1喝he1啤pi2酒jiu3", which means _I like drinking beer_. Your original sentence "我喜欢喝一杯啤酒" means _I like drinking one glass of beer_ (not two glasses, not three glasses, I like drinking exactly one glass of beer)  the last two sentences, however, sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

喜欢(xi3 huan1) means to *like*

要(yao4) tends to realize the action

想(xiang3) means to *want*, but you don't have to realize it. Sometimes it is just an expression of your desire.